# При редактировании статьи, не отправляется выдает ошибку

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

Когда создаю статью, загружаю изображение,все отлично работает и создается. Но при редактировании статьи, на сервер отправляется пустой массив. Почему? Вот код который использую для добавления статьи

```
$('#form').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $('#form');
        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url     : form.attr("action"),
            type    : form.attr("method"),
            data    : formData,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
            },
            error :function( errors ) {
                output = "<div class='alert alert-danger'><h4><i class='icon fa fa-ban'></i> Возникла ошибка!</h4><ul>";
                $.each(errors.responseJSON, function(index, error){
                    output += "<li>" + error + "</li>";
                });
                output += "</ul></div>";
                $('#append').html(output);
            },
            success: function(data){
                output = "<div class='alert alert-success'><h4><i class='icon fa fa-check'></i> Готово!</h4><ul>";
                output +=  data.success;
                output += "</ul></div>";
                $('#append').html(output);
                setTimeout(function(){
                    window.location.replace('{{ url('panel/catalog') }}')}, 3500
                );
            }
        })
    })
```

вот код при редактировании статьи. Все тоже самое, только метод меняется

```
 $('#form').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $('#form');
        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url     : form.attr("action"),
            type    : 'patch',
            data    : formData,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
            },
            error :function( errors ) {
                output = "<div class='alert alert-danger'><h4><i class='icon fa fa-ban'></i> Возникла ошибка!</h4><ul>";
                $.each(errors.responseJSON, function(index, error){
                    output += "<li>" + error + "</li>";
                });
                output += "</ul></div>";
                $('#append').html(output);
            },
            success: function(data){
                output = "<div class='alert alert-success'><h4><i class='icon fa fa-check'></i> Готово!</h4><ul>";
                output +=  data.success;
                output += "</ul></div>";
                $('#append').html(output);
                setTimeout(function(){
                    window.location.replace('{{ url('panel/catalog') }}')}, 3500
                );
            }
        })
    })
```

Comment: потому что в методе `patch` нельзя слать `FormData`, ну или просто чтение на сервере не верным способом

Comment: А как тогда обновить изображения в статьях, если без формдаты изображение не загрузить?

Comment: [Note: Since HTML forms only support POST and GET, PUT and DELETE methods will be spoofed by automatically adding a `_method` hidden field to your form.](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html#opening-a-form), скорее всего подойдет и для `PATCH`

Comment: и в качестве альтернативы предлагают еще использовать: `x-www-form-urlencoded` Тип