# Serialize() и FormData одновременно

Tags: jquery, ajax

Возможно ли одновременно через аякс отправлять и формдату и сериализацию?
В формдате отправлять изображение, а в сериализации просто инпуты. Если возможно, покажите на примере пожалуйста

Comment: В формдате добавьте поле и запишите туда серриализацию, и отправте все вместе.

Comment: Дело в том, что я плохо владею jquery, и даже не представляю как это сделать

Comment: Приведите код который у вас хоть что то делает и от него можно плясать. Вы же как то делаете запросы аякс...

Comment: Вот код http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/545084/При-редактировании-статьи-не-отправляется-выдает-ошибку Идеально работает при создании ресурса, а при редактировании не пашет. Нужно разделить текстовые инпуты и изображение для отправки методом serialize и formdata соответственно